# In Facebook, how to cleanly link to a Japanese Wikipedia URL that contains a ・ (nakaguro)?

Tags: facebook

On Facebook, try to post a Japanese Wikipedia URL containing a `・` (nakaguro) character (like `http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/レオナルド・ダ・ヴィンチ`) and you will get a broken link:

[image: Facebook 中黒 link]

Notice how `・ダ・ヴィンチ` has failed to become a link (red arrow above), probably because `・` is mistaken as a kind of delimiter. Notice also that the preview does not have this problem.

One option could be to post the encoded URL, but my message would look really ugly:

https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%AC%E3%82%AA%E3%83%8A%E3%83%AB%E3%83%89%E3%83%BB%E3%83%80%E3%83%BB%E3%83%B4%E3%82%A3%E3%83%B3%E3%83%81

How can I solve this, and post this as an URL which:

- is nice-looking
- actually works when clicked

?

Removing the link altogether is not a good option, because I actually need the preview for another link. Also a scenario that happens often: I take a picture of ヴィクトル・スタルヒン and I post it with the text "Hey I just met [http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/ヴィクトル](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%B4%E3%82%A3%E3%82%AF%E3%83%88%E3%83%AB)・スタルヒン in the street!". So my question is really for links inside the text part. Also, I have hopes that a solution would also work in comments.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to post a link, along with the preview? Isn't the clickable preview enough?

If it is, then you can write/paste the URL, let the preview load, then *delete* the URL and write your actual message. The preview will stay there and your post won't contain any URLs, nakaguro problems or not.

Comment: Actually I most often have another link which I want to be previewed instead. Or for instance, I take a picture of ヴィクトル・スタルヒン and I post it with the text "Hey I just met https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/ヴィクトル・スタルヒン in the street!". So my question is really for when preview alone is not enough. I will update my question to make it clearer.